# angular2 - add error class after validation

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I've searched a lot but cannot get this to work as expected.
So I have form validator which checks if email is valid and sets *emailValid*. If it is not valid I want to add *has-error* class to form group. Problem is that it adds class *has-error* only if *emailValid* is set to false in its initial state. So I can add class only at the begining but cannot after email validation is proceeded.

**In HTML template**

```
<div class="form-group label-floating" [class.has-error]="!emailValid">
```

**In Component**

```
let mail_regex = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$");

this.emailValid = mail_regex.test(this.model.email);
```

Although this part uses same variable *emailValid* it works just fine. So I am realy confused.

```
<p *ngIf="!emailValid" i18n><strong>Email is not valid.</strong> Please write valid email.</p>
```

Thanks for answer.

**Whole Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { User } from '../models/user';
import { UserService } from '../user.service'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in-form',
  templateUrl: './sign-in-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in-form.component.css']
})
export class SignInFormComponent implements OnInit {

  private errorMessage;
  private successMessage;

  private repeatPassword;

  private emailValid;
  private emailNotExists;
  private passwordValid;
  private passwordEqual;
  private firstnameValid;
  private lastnameValid;

  private notValid;
  private repairErrors;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    this.notValid = false;
    this.emailValid = true;
    this.emailNotExists = true;
    this.passwordValid = true;
    this.passwordEqual = true;
    this.firstnameValid = true;
    this.lastnameValid = true;
    this.repairErrors = false;

  }


  ngOnInit(){}

  private model = new User('', '', '', '', '', '');

  onSubmit() {
    this.emailValidator();
    this.passwordValidator();
    this.firstnameValidator();
    this.lastnameValidator();

    if(!this.notValid) {
      this.userService.createUser(this.model)
      .subscribe(res => this.successMessage = res.code == '201', error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);

      this.repairErrors = false
    }
    else {
      this.repairErrors = true
    }


  }

  emailValidator() {
    //check if exists
    if (this.model.email.length > 1){
      this.userExists();
    }

    //check if valid
    let mail_regex = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$");

    this.emailValid = mail_regex.test(this.model.email);

    this.notValid = !(this.emailValid && this.emailNotExists &&
      this.passwordValid && this. passwordEqual &&
      this.firstnameValid && this.lastnameValid);
    console.log(this.notValid)
  }

  passwordValidator(){
    this.passwordValid = this.model.password.length > 5 && this.model.password.length < 78;
    this.passwordEqual = this.model.password == this.repeatPassword

    this.notValid = !(this.emailValid && this.emailNotExists &&
      this.passwordValid && this. passwordEqual &&
      this.firstnameValid && this.lastnameValid);
  }

  firstnameValidator(){
    let name_regex = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z ]+$');
    this.firstnameValid = name_regex.test(this.model.firstname) && this.model.firstname.length > 1;

    this.notValid = !(this.emailValid && this.emailNotExists &&
      this.passwordValid && this. passwordEqual &&
      this.firstnameValid && this.lastnameValid);
  }

  lastnameValidator(){
    let name_regex = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z ]+$');
    this.lastnameValid = name_regex.test(this.model.lastname) && this.model.lastname.length > 1;

    this.notValid = !(this.emailValid && this.emailNotExists &&
      this.passwordValid && this. passwordEqual &&
      this.firstnameValid && this.lastnameValid);
  }


  userExists() {

    if (this.model.email != '') {
      this.userService.getUser(this.model.email).subscribe(
                      res => this.emailNotExists = res.code == '0',
                      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3">
<div *ngIf="errorMessage" class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <p i18n><strong>Error on server. </strong>Please try again or contact administrator</p>
</div>
<div *ngIf="successMessage" class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <p i18n><strong>Success. </strong>Please check your email and activate your account.</p>
</div>
<div *ngIf="notValid" class="alert alert-dismissible alert-warning">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <p *ngIf="!emailNotExists" i18n><strong>Email exists.</strong> Please choose another email or login.</p>
    <p *ngIf="!emailValid" i18n><strong>Email is not valid.</strong> Please write valid email.</p>
    <p *ngIf="!passwordValid" i18n><strong>Password is not valid.</strong>It should be at least 6 characters long.</p>
    <p *ngIf="!passwordEqual" i18n><strong>Passwords are not equal.</strong> Write passwords again.</p>
    <p *ngIf="!firstnameValid" i18n><strong>First name is not valid.</strong> It should be at least 2 characters long and contains only letters.</p>
    <p *ngIf="!lastnameValid" i18n><strong>Last name is not valid</strong> It should be at least 2 characters long and contains only letters.</p>
</div>
<div class="well bs-component">
        <legend>
            <h1 class="text-primary" i18n="Sign up form">Sign up</h1>
        </legend>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-lg-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1">
                <div class="form-group label-floating" [class.has-error]="!emailValid">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label" i18n>Email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" (change)="emailValidator()" [(ngModel)]="model.email" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" id="username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group  label-floating">
                    <label for="password1" class="control-label" i18n>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.password" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" id="password1">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group  label-floating">
                    <label for="password2" class="control-label" i18n>Confirm password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" (change)="passwordValidator()" [(ngModel)]="repeatPassword" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" id="password2">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group  label-floating">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label" i18n>First name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" (change)="firstnameValidator()" [(ngModel)]="model.firstname" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" id="firstname">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group  label-floating">
                    <label for="lastname" class="control-label" i18n>Last name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" (change)="lastnameValidator()" [(ngModel)]="model.lastname" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" id="lastname">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group  label-floating">
                    <label for="company" class="control-label" i18n>Company</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.company" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" id="company">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group  label-floating">
                    <label for="country" class="control-label" i18n>Country</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.country" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" id="country">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-offset-3">
                <button type="submit" class="col-md-8 btn btn-raised btn-primary" (click)="onSubmit()" i18n>Sign up</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<div *ngIf="repairErrors" class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <p i18n><strong>Cannot submit.</strong> Please repair your errors first.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: To answer your question, you should show some more code. The important thing to know would be, when `emailValid` is updated. I guess that the change detection just does not work in that case. Besides doing the form visualization on your own, you might consider using Angular2 forms, see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Comment: Why don't you implement it as custom validator and use the error class Angular forms add automatically?

Comment: The problem is that it works with error message but doesn't with class change. I looked at Angular2 docs and I found something similar with [class.clicked] but doesent work in my case. It is al the time in initial state.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Bacause I want to use bootstarps error class.

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way of using angular 2 form validation, but even if you want to do this, you have to make function which will be called on input change where you will pass the value of the input and call:

```
let mail_regex = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$");
```

this.emailValid = mail_regex.test(this.model.email);

Comment: I have it. The only problem is that it shows error message when is not valid mail, but does not change class of form group.

Comment: Try replacing it [class.has-error]="!emailValid" with [ngClass]="{'has-error': !emailValid}"

Comment: Tried - It also adds class but does note react to variable changes.

Comment: Can you please post whole component so I can debug it?

Comment: Just add it to original post.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom validator like this :

```
export class PatterValidator {
    public static patternValidator ( pattern ) {
            return ( c ) => {
                if ( pattern ) {
                    if ( ! c.value || new RegExp(pattern ).test( c.value ) ) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    return {
                        pattern : {
                            text : '<strong>Email is not valid.</strong> Please write valid email.' 
                        }
                    };
                }
                return null;
            };
        }

}
```

And add it to your control like this :

```
        let yourPattern = "^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$";

        let validators = Validators.compose( [
            PatterValidator.patternValidator(yourPattern),
            anyOtherValidator ...
        ] );
        emailControl.setValidators( validators );
```

And then you can use it in your template like :

```
<p *ngIf="!emailValid" i18n [innerHtml]="emailValid.errors.pattern.text"></p>
```

Comment: Validation is not problem. Problem is that Error message is shown/hidden dependent on emailValid variable, but class does not change on variable change.

Answer (score 0):

Found problem. It works with my custom CSS classes but doesn't with *Material Design for Bootstrap*. Reason is that it overwrites its own current classes while you're using floating labels. Therefore it works as expected if I use my own class for example:
**CSS**
`.selected{
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}`

**HTML**

```
[ngClass]="{'selected': emailValid}
```

**or**

```
[class.selected]="emailValid"
```